# Filter Data of Object Model in C# Entity-Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Assume A as object model that have property ID(int) and Status(Bool)
and B as object model also have ID(int) and Status(Bool)

And I want get data from A filtered by it's property. if it an sql query like 
`"select * from A where A.Status=True and A.ID in (Select ID from B Where B.Status=True)`, 
I don't now how to make var C = that query..

`var c = A.Where(a=>a.Status==True && a.ID .....)` I don't know how to apply "`in`" here

I'm really new to use C# Entity Framework.

Comment: If you designed your database correctly, the table A and B should have a relationship and after imported to your model, A should have some navigation property pointing to B, then you can access easily and check the Status. It all depends on your database design.

Comment: @Hopeless , thanks, sorry about the database and all the model not created by me, it's from server work use TFS for practice. I just can make line command in codebehind c#. Now how the scenarios just like what I write above. Assume there's no relationship between that both

Comment: If there is no relationship I think you should convert the query to local IEnumerable (using ToList() or some others), then you can do all kinds of LINQ freely.

Comment: @Hopeless , sorry i take back  my comment before. I just got information, well it it have navigation property between A an B , so can you please tell me how to get var c as the scenario above? assume the navigation properties is "AB"

Comment: So it is just simple like this `A.Where(a=>a.Status==true && a.AB.Status == true)`

Comment: Okay thank you so much, I want to try it first, thank you...

Comment: you're welcome, in case there is no navigation property, you can also write query directly like this: `A.Where(a=>a.Status && B.Where(b=>b.Status).Any(b=>b.ID == a.ID))`

Comment: @hopeless It's works, thaks a lot :D

Comment: @Hopeless Make your comment an answer so that Ana can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If A and B has some relationship and is represented by a navigation property named AB, then the query can be simple like this:

```
var c = A.Where(a=>a.Status && a.AB.Status);
```

If they don't have any relationship, then you can also query directly like this (although the performance won't be as good as the above):

```
var c = A.Where(a=>a.Status && B.Where(b=>b.Status).Any(b=>b.ID == a.ID))
```